# SQL select not viewing correct data

Tags: sql, select

I have earlier been using MySQL and there I could get the correct response with this select query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE COLUMN1 NOT IN ('Done', 'Closed') 
  AND COLUMN2 IN ('Dude1', 'Dude2', 'Dude3')
```

Now we have changed db to oracle and there it leaves out if COLUMN1 have no value in it. In another words, it's null/empty.

I have tried what I believe would be the correct way to make the query but it behaves not as I was hoping. Maybe someone have a solution that I could retrieve same information as in MySQL.

Last attempt I ended up with this query

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM TABLE 
 WHERE COLUMN1 NOT IN ('Done', 'Closed') 
    OR COLUMN1 IS NULL 
   AND COLUMN2 IN ('Dude1', 'Dude2', 'Dude3')
```

When I run this query I get all that have null/empty as value in COLUMN1 but I also get Dude6 in COLUMN2 from the reply... and I can't figure out how I could do it any other way..

If I remove

```
OR Column1 IS NULL
```

I won't get the mysterious Dude6 as responses but I also won't get the rows where column1 is empty/null and with Dude1 in it for example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need parentheses around your `OR` expression:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE 
  (COLUMN1 NOT IN ('Done','Closed') OR COLUMN1 IS NULL)
  AND COLUMN2 IN ('Dude1','Dude2','Dude3')
```